# How would I design a cable line that doesn't leak heat to the ground surface?

Tags: cables, high-voltage, power-dissipation

A loaded underground power cable dissipates some power as heat which heats the surroundings. The following scenario is possible in regions where large amounts of snow accumulate on the ground during winter.

At some point (late autumn or early winter) temperature gets below water freezing point. Snow starts accumulating. Then in spring temperature rises and snow starts melting. Loose heat from a cable line can be enough to accelerate melting of snow right above the cable line. The same scenario can happen if there's sudden warm weather in winter - recently accumulated snow starts melting.

This may cause the following curious observation: you're in some field or forest, everything is covered in snow, expect a narrow trace running across that area where snow has melted to the ground. The power cable is immediately traceable.

I've also heard that sometimes cables are not plotted on publicly available location plans and this is done to keep the cables secret (some government organizations might do that, I have no evidence of that, let's just assume this happens). Clearly leaking heat which melts snow and makes the cable traceable in warm weather makes it hard to keep the cable location secret. Spotting and plotting such cable requires no special equipment and no special skills - just take a GPS tracker in your pocket and walk the trace and if anyone questions you - then say you're going for a walk.

How can a cable line be designed such that it doesn't leak heat enough to make it traceable in the scenario above? An underground cable is covered with at least half meter of ground and even that is not enough. Obviously adding more thermal insulation would reduce the effect but not eliminate it completely.

How could one design a cable line that doesn't leak heat to ground surface?

Comment: Superconductors?

Comment: Use a heavier cable (less heat per unit length for a given current), and bury the cable below the frost line so that even in winter, the heat will be better conducted downward rather than upward.

Comment: @DaveTweed How would burying the cable below the frost line cause heat not to be dissipated upwards?

Comment: Because liquid ground water conducts better than frost, and also, below the frost line, the soil by definition is already warmer than the surface.

Comment: @DaveTweed Okay, it conducts better but still imperfect. Less heat will be dissipated upwards, but that wouldn't prevent the leakage entirely.

Comment: I never said it would. See my FIRST comment.

Comment: As explained by other commentators, it is not possible to make a cable completely undetectable. Assuming that secrecy was really important, a more practical approach would be to have no cable, and a generator on site. But the value of this approach is highly questionable as well in the era of ubiquitous aerial photography.

Comment: To add: Insulating a (highly) dissipating cable is a bad idea. If the ground around a cable can't keep it cool, that means insulating it will cause it to heat up significantly. Significant heating of a cable is bad for many reasons, obvious ones would be danger or failure of plastics inside the cable, maybe a less obvious one is higher resistance, which then causes higher losses, and then you get a whole other kind of snow-ball to deal with.

Comment: You can minimize heat transfer to the ground by using an aerial cable.

Comment: @ThePhoton How would that help?

Comment: Air is a very good insulator.

Comment: @ThePhoton Where will heat go? Melt the cable?

Comment: Run the cables in a conduit, pump cooled insulating liquid thought the conduits. The heat comes back to your heat exchanger. :P But your cables could still be traced, right? There is going to be a power meter on one end...

Comment: @Tyler A power meter on the feeding end only tells how much power is consumed, not where the cable goes, doesn't it?

Comment: @sharptooth If I know where one end of the cable is, and I really really want to find the other end, even if it undetectable under the snow, I can just start digging...

Comment: @Tyler That's very expensive and the fact of such determined digging will be spotted pretty soon. EMF or metal detectors could be much more practical. The problem with melting snow is that you need zero specialized tools and very little time to trace and plot the cable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make cables undetectable in terms of waste heat:

- burring them deeper
- increasing conductor diameter
- increasing the voltage

In the end, all these solutions cost extra money and are not implemented in practice, AFAIK.

Furthermore, there are more reliable detection techniques than observing snow patterns, such as metal detectors.

If fact, I would question your statement about underground power cables being secret. Information about such cables is actually widely available. Have you ever seen this sign?

[image]

Comment: Sure I have seen such signs. However I've heard numerous rumors of cables being damaged that were not plotted and unhappy folks in uniform would arrive on the site soon after damage.

Comment: Those are rumours. Unless the power is for a private or secret organization, the location of power lines is essentially public. Even those secret service lines have to be catalogued for safety reasons somewhere. Actually, the real problem in some places is badly documented maps. Some places we actually have a poor idea of decades old infrastructure.

Comment: Did the unhappy folks bring memory erasers to sanitize the brains of the diggers (jokingly)? Seriously, I think it's the lack of communication rather than secrecy, combined with life-threatening risk of electric shock, that made those unhappy guys appear.

Answer (score 0):

Run the cable along a natural watercourse.

You'll have to design your facility to exploit the terrain, but that's not a problem, right?

I am assuming the project budget allows you to site your facility at arbitrary locations!

In practice, superconductors are probably cheaper - but take care that their cooling systems doesn't leave an equally traceable cold track...

Comment: It is a problem if you want your cable to go to a particular location.

Comment: And you could get the currents mixed up. +1.

Comment: Two useless suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Who are you hiding this from? If the military is searching for it, they could find it with metal detectors, EMF radiation locators, FLIRs, or ground penetrating radar... If mild snow melting in specific seasons is your biggest problem, you're probably being caught by natives, who don't care, or guerillas involved in sketchy stuff...

Regardless, use a directional drill with a larger OD, thick walled, cast iron pipe to maximize heat transfer and shielding...